# swagger swagger-codegen-maven-plugin generate Default Api interface

Tags: swagger

i'm trying to use swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to generate my interface .
after compiling with the plugin - it generates all the files correctly but for some reason
the interface name is DefaultApi.

i looked for some configuration that i can change the name of the interface that been generated but didnt find the solution for that.

any idea on that??

Answer (score 22):

"DefaultApi" is used when there's no `tags` specified for the endpoint.

For example, [this endpoint](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L398) will be put in a class named "UserApi" since the `tags` is set to `User`.

You will need to update the spec to include proper `tags` for endpoints to avoid using "DefaultApi"

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Starting in [OpenAPI Generator v7.0.0](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v7.0.0), one can use [openapi-normalizer](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization/#openapi-normalizer) with the rule `SET_TAGS_FOR_ALL_OPERATIONS` to force all operations using a particular tag.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is it possible to remove the word API??

Comment: Yes, that's possible by customizing swagger codegen (free, open-source). You can override [toApiName](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/DefaultCodegen.java#L1117) method in the code generator.

Comment: will try it , tnx for your answer

Comment: As far as I know the API-Name is derived from the first path token. It has nothing to do with the tags.

The class got the Name from the first path token /user

Comment: @MatthiasHoefel is correct. Which is why I was here reading this. Our first path token is a path parameter '{productId}' and now our interface is called productIdApi, which is very annoying.

Comment: I discovered that when you set <useTags>true</useTags> in the configOptions section of the maven plugin, it WILL actually use the first tag to generate the api class name.

Comment: OpenAPI maven generator - there is a `apiNameSuffix` param that can add a `SuffixHere` or something to the end so that it reads `DefaultSuffixHere` instead of `DefaultApi`. that was good enough for me in my case i think.

Answer (score 0):

Side note for `<useTags>true<useTags>`, you need to specify tags both for root of your specs file and for each endpoint you have in your file.

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: 
  version: "1.0"
  description: 
tags:
  - name: myApi
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
paths:
  /thisPathWontAffectTheGeneratedClassNames
    get:
      operationId: 
      description: 
      tags:
        - myTag
      ...
```

Resulting API: MyTagApi